# What effects does this assignment to the typeless blank identifier have?

Tags: go

I found the following code in `crypto/sha256/sha256.go`:

```
func putUint32(x []byte, s uint32) {
    _ = x[3]
    x[0] = byte(s >> 24)
    x[1] = byte(s >> 16)
    x[2] = byte(s >> 8)
    x[3] = byte(s)
}
```

All I see that this assignment to the blank identifier would do is panic if `len(x)` wasn't at least 4, which isn't even an effect of the assignment as much as it is of the evaluation of `x[3]`. So, wouldn't the following (shorter, more desirable code) be equivalent?

```
func putUint32(x []byte, s uint32) {
    x[3] = byte(s)
    x[2] = byte(s >> 8)
    x[1] = byte(s >> 16)
    x[0] = byte(s >> 24)
}
```

If so, why wasn't it written this way?

Comment: I don't know an actual answer, but I'm guessing that this is an attempt to elicit a segfault from *accessing* out-of-bounds memory, instead of *setting* out-of-bounds memory, which could be more dangerous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `_ =` assignment itself does nothing, but the index expression assigned to it is there to access the last element needed in the slice before a number of other lower index operations. This is an optimization to hint to the compiler that all the lower index operations on that value are safe, and the bounds checks can be elided. This is often call "Bounds Check Elimination"

The primary reason the latter example isn't used is a second optimization, the bytes need to be read in-order so that the compiler can coalesce them into multi-byte loads.

Comment: Wouldn't the OP suggestion of assigning "x[3] = byte(s)" as the first operation in the function create the same effect then? Not questioning your explanation, just trying to understand it fully.

Comment: @eugenioy: you'd have to look at the compiled machine code and benchmarks. Since this is a highly optimized code path, my guess is that the in-order access comes out faster. It also may no longer be needed in some cases, but since it's not detrimental to performance it will probably stay for he time being.

Comment: @eugenioy: I could be mistaken, but I do seem to recall there being talk about the `_ = x[3]` construct being used to specifically trigger the bounds check elimination, in which case the latter example wouldn't have the same effect.

Comment: The code is constructed to trigger two optimizations.  The first is to execute a single bounds check for the function. This optimization will be triggered when `x[3] = byte(s)` is moved to the first statement. The second optimization is to coalesce the single byte loads into a single multi-byte load.  This optimization is only triggered when loads are in the order is written in the function.  See [amd64.rules](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/196e67f95bd00681eab56b5da4eea28b0ca53e51/src/cmd/compile/internal/ssa/gen/AMD64.rules#L1532-L1534).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @CeriseLimón, I was looking for that!